# Timer not working for d.py giveaway command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm making a giveaway command and I tried wrapping the whole thing in a while loop, but of course that then only counts down when a reaction is added. So, instead, I included the timer at the end. But that doesn't work either and it no longer counts down.

For it to countdown and then give the winner.

````py
    @app_commands.command(name="giveaway", description="Start a giveaway")
    @app_commands.guild_only()
    async def giveaway(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, winners: int, duration: str, prize: str):
        await interaction.response.defer()
        embed = discord.Embed(description="**Creating giveaway...**", color=discord.Color.blue())
        await interaction.followup.send(embed=embed)
        msg = await interaction.original_response()
 
        # Convert duration argument into seconds
        pos = ["s", "m", "h", "d"]
        time_dict = {"s" : 1, "m" : 60, "h" : 3600, "d" : 3600*24}
        unit = duration[-1]
        if unit not in pos:
            await interaction.response.send_message(f'Answer Time With A Proper Unit (s, m, h, d)')
            return
        try:
            val = int(duration[:-1])
        except:
            await interaction.response.send_message(f'Time Must Be A Integer!')
            return
        time_in_sec = val * time_dict[unit]
 
        # Calculate end time
        end_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=time_in_sec)
 
        # Format the duration into seconds/hours/days
        if unit == 's':
            formatted_duration = f"{val} seconds(s)"
        elif unit == 'm':
            formatted_duration = f"{val} minute(s)"
        elif unit == 'h':
            formatted_duration = f"{val} hour(s)"
        else:
            formatted_duration = f"{val} day(s)"
 
        # Create the embed
        embed = discord.Embed(title=" New Giveaway! ", color=discord.Color.blue())
        embed.description = f"**Prize:** {prize}\n**Hosted By:** {interaction.user.mention}\n**Ends In:** {formatted_duration}"
        embed.timestamp = end_time # Set timestamp as end time
 
        # Send message and add reaction
        await msg.edit(embed=embed)
        await msg.add_reaction('\U0001f389')
            
        # Convert the remaining time into days/hours/minutes/seconds
        days = time_in_sec // (3600 * 24)
        hours = (time_in_sec % (3600 * 24)) // 3600
        minutes = ((time_in_sec % (3600 * 24)) % 3600) // 60
        seconds = ((time_in_sec % (3600 * 24)) % 3600) % 60
            
        # Format the remaining time into a string
        if days > 0:
            formatted_duration = f"{days} day(s) {hours} hour(s) {minutes} minute(s) {seconds} second(s)"
        elif hours > 0:
            formatted_duration = f"{hours} hour(s) {minutes} minute(s) {seconds} seconds"
        elif minutes > 0:
            formatted_duration = f"{minutes} minute(s) {seconds} second(s)"
        else:
            formatted_duration = f"{seconds} second(s)"

        embed.description= f"**Prize:** {prize}\n**Hosted By:** {interaction.user.mention}\n**Ends In:** {formatted_duration}"
        embed.color = discord.Color.blue()
        await msg.edit(embed=embed)

        msg = await interaction.channel.fetch_message(msg.id)
        users = [user async for user in msg.reactions[0].users()]
        users.pop(users.index(self.bot.user))
        winners = []

        # Wait for a reaction
        reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=lambda reaction, user: user in users)

        # Update embed description with remaining time every 10 seconds
        while time_in_sec > 0:
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            time_in_sec -= 5
            formatted_duration = f"{days} day(s) {hours} hour(s) {minutes} minute(s) {seconds} second(s)"
            embed.description= f"**Prize:** {prize}\n**Hosted By:** {interaction.user.mention}\n**Ends In:** {formatted_duration}"
            await msg.edit(embed=embed)

        # Choose random winners and edit embed
        for i in range(winners):
            winner = random.choice(users)
            winners.append(winner.mention)
            users.pop(users.index(winner)) # Remove winner from list of users

            embed = discord.Embed(title=" Giveaway ended! ",
                                        description=f"**Prize:** {prize}\n**Winners:** {' '.join(winners)}",
                                        color=discord.Color.blue()
                                        )
            await msg.edit(embed=embed)

        if len(winners) == 0:
             await interaction.channel.send("No one entered the giveaway :(")
        else:
            for i in range(min(len(winners), len(users))):
                winner = random.choice(users)
                winners.append(winner.mention)
                users.remove(winner) # Remove winner from list of users

                embed = discord.Embed(title=" Giveaway ended! ",
                                            description=f"**Prize:** {prize}\n**Winners:** {' '.join(winners)}",
                                            color=discord.Color.blue()
                                            )
                await msg.edit(embed=embed)

            await interaction.channel.send(f"Congratulations! {' '.join(winners)}")```
````

Answer (score 0):

Editing like that in a loop is very unnecessary, spams Discord's API, and will get you ratelimited.

Discord has built-in support for this. You can just use a relative timestamp (`"R"`) & it will count down client-side for the users.

`utils.format_dt` does this for you: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=format_dt#discord.utils.format_dt